# How to use mindmup js in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys im trying to create a html page which includes "mindmup js".i included all dependencies given in the readme file Link: https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs .but unable to make it work.documentation is not that much clear.if you have any examples on how to work with mindmup-mapjs.min.js please post.your answers will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Show is some of your attempts, we can show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

check out the test folder in github (https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs/tree/master/test), there is an index.html there that shows how to wire things up and set up the editor. in short, you need to

1. initialise a MAPJS.content object with your map details
2. create a DOMMapWidget somewhere on the web page
3. connect the two using a MapModel

Comment: Thank you  so much Gojko Adzic ill try it out and get back to you if i face any difficulties..

Comment: Gojko Adzic i tried the example came with test folder and cannot able to make it work.please help me

Comment: @Gojko Adzic, any ideas why launching `test/index.html` is showing something ugly like no css was applied to the html page ? and can't interact with it ..

Comment: @BipBip most likely, you've not pulled the dependencies. (see the instructions here: https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs). if that's not an issue, which browser/version are you using? are there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah I actually didn't read the whole stuff , thanks for the answer tho :)